# How to persist data from useLocation()?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

is there a way to persist data from useLocation() ?

Basically I'm sending data that is located on a nested collection from firebase
(There's a lot of background on my question/explanation, you can just skip to the important bit)

Usually you have no issues when you only have one collection you can always access the UID pretty much from anywhere by sending it from the App.js for example:

```
function App() {

  const [user, setUser] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    auth.onAuthStateChanged((authUser) => {

      if (authUser) {
        setUser(authUser);
      } else {
        setUser(false);
      }
    })
  }, [])

 return (
    < div >
        <Router>
        <Switch>

          <Route path = "/SomePath">
            <SomeLocation user={user}/>
          </Route>

     </Switch>
  </Router>
</div >
   );
 }

export default App;
```

and since the user have all the data you need to get any other piece of information (usually) you don't need to worry about nested collections however, what if I'm using nested collections ?

if you want to access all the data from a nested collection that's also fine you do not require any other extra information apart from the user

Ej:

```
useEffect(() => { 
  const dbRef= db.collection("users").doc(user.uid).collection("someCollection")
  dbRef.onSnapshot(snapshot => {
    const tempData = [];
    snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      const data = doc.data();
      
      tempData.push(data);
    });
    setDataSomewhere(tempData);
  })
 }, [user]);
```

However how you get the data of the uid of an specific document inside a nested location with just the user ? you can't (as far as I'm aware)

**The Important bit without all the background**

EJ:

if you have let's say a "parent" and he adds "students" which is my case:

[image]

and I wanted to edit this "student" that is in a nested collection, let's make an example on the first one the one named "alfonsa" this is the edit form which is in another "/Path"

[image]

The way I'm handling the data of the student is the following, when you check the student and you select the edit icon from the data-table it sends some data through useLocation()

```
//PATH-A (The one with the data table)

const editStudent= {
  pathname: '/EDIT_STUDENT',
  data: studentData
}

const editStudents= () => {
  if(studentData== 0)
  {
    window.alert("Select a student")
  }
  else {
    history.push(editStudent);
  }
};

///EDIT_STUDENT (Edit form)

let studentData= useLocation();
let data = studentData.data;

console.log(data)

const uid = data[0].uid <- Here I get that student specific uid
```

This is what the console log returns (All correct data):

[image]

However all the data disappears on refresh (which makes sense because is no longer getting the useLocation data from the previous "/path" location) this is the question:

**How can I keep/store/maintain that data that comes from the useLocation() on refresh**

Any help/tip/example is welcome

**Forgot to add this**
This is basically what comes up when I refresh

[image]

**UPDATE** So I tried localStorage() as someone mention but now I can't access the data because is coming as a string how can I separate the data ?

This is how I'm storing the data:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const localStorageEstData = window.localStorage.getItem("students");
  localStorageEstData && setStudentsData(JSON.parse(localStorageEstData));
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
  window.localStorage.setItem("students", JSON.stringify(studentsData));
}, [studentsData]);
```

This is how I'm getting the data + how it shows in console:

`let data = window.localStorage.getItem("estudiantes")`

[image]

is coming as a whole string how can I separate it ?

Comment: What is `useLocation()` returning?

Comment: useLocation is returning all the student data is selected so that would be: 
uid, name, school, course. let me console log it.

Comment: "How can I keep/store/maintain that data that comes from the useLocation() on refresh "  The same way you persist _any_ data on refresh -- put it in localStorage, pass it through as a URL param, or read it from the database again.

Comment: How can you read it from the database "again" ? if you refresh the uid is gonna go back to null. and it will never go through the database collection.

Comment: @DanielBeck doesn't localStorage works based on current path? like if I store in localStorage students data in PathA and I move that data to PathB won't that value be the same as what I'm trying to do since localStorage saves on current path? or am I wrong and it persist everywhere ? Can you provide an example ?

Comment: okay nvm I was wrong however how do I pick specific data from the localStorage @DanielBeck ? like if I wanted the uid how can I take it from the localStorage ? `let data = window.localStorage.getItem("students")` but how I get the uid ? I can't just do const `uid = data.uid.value` or `data[0].uid`

Comment: This might be worth a read through: https://blog.logrocket.com/localstorage-javascript-complete-guide/

Comment: (To turn that JSON string back into data use `JSON.parse()`.  To get at a specific bit of data, such as an individual student's uid, store it under a known key e.g. `localStorage.setItem("currentStudentUID", data[0].uid)` so you know where to look for it later; or only store the data for the specific student you're looking at, instead of storing the entire set.)

Comment: I have parse it and I wasn't able to do that sadly unless I did it wrong will show you @DanielBeck , let me try first to store only what I require instead of the whole thing

Comment: if I do what you say of storing specific value let's say localStorage.setItem("currentStudentUID", data[0].uid) when I come back it will scream at me because I haven't set data[0].uid no where. is not as easy as a regular value. That's why I send the WHOLE data because if I try to be "specific" when I come back it can scream at me while if I send the whole data is okay because if is null when I come back it will not scream at me, it will stay as null until I select another student

Comment: @DanielBeck the correct answer was indeed to parse it but I was doing it wrong this worked: const data = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("students")). Post an answer so I can upvote you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since no one posted an answer I will based on what @Daniel Beck said

Instead of using useLocation() that is to pass data from one /Path to another is better to use localStorage for multiple reasons and the more important one is to persist/keep data on refresh.

if you use useLocation() and you refresh the data will disappear because is no longer parsing data from one /Path to another. However the localStorage will persist on refresh which is why is more useful for this case

simple solution for me was:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const localStorageEstData = window.localStorage.getItem("students");
  localStorageEstData && setStudentsData(JSON.parse(localStorageEstData));
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
  window.localStorage.setItem("students", JSON.stringify(estudiantesData));
}, [studentsData]);
```

and then in the other end:

```
const data = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("students"))
const uid = data[0].uid
```

that way I have access to all the information not just the uid